# How to use extender provider in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code I want to use it in my form
how to do it?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
'...
<ProvideProperty("NullableTextBox", typeof(TextBox) Is )>
Partial Public Class NullableTextBox
    Inherits Component
    Implements IExtenderProvider
    Dim _nullables As Dictionary(Of Control, Boolean) = New Dictionary(Of Control, Boolean)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is the get part of the extender property.
    ''' It is actually a method because it takes the control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="control"></param>
    <DefaultValue(False), _
     Category("Data")> _
    Public Function GetNullableBinding(ByVal control As Control) As Boolean
        Dim nullableBinding As Boolean = False
        _nullables.TryGetValue(control, nullableBinding)
        Return nullableBinding
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This is the set part of the extender property.
    ''' It is actually a method because it takes the control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="control"></param>
    ''' <param name="nullable"></param>
    Public Sub SetNullableBinding(ByVal control As Control, ByVal nullable As Boolean)
        If _nullables.ContainsKey(control) Then
            _nullables(control) = nullable
        Else
            _nullables.Add(control, nullable)
        End If

        If nullable Then
            ' Add a parse event handler.
            AddHandler control.DataBindings("Text").Parse, AddressOf Me.NullableExtender_Parse
        End If

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' When parsing, set the value to null if the value is empty.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    Private Sub NullableExtender_Parse(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ConvertEventArgs)
        If (e.Value.ToString.Length = 0) Then
            e.Value = Nothing
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you think this code does?

Comment: Answer, you don't use this code in the form.  This is a component that you create an instance of this form in the form.

Comment: I want to add this component to my form  .. how to do it